# How to pass Jquery accordion attributes to panel while page load, not on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Hi i am opening the accordion panel of a page from external links. Its is working fine but the page is not coming to the top where the accordion panel is active . At some points it is offscreen(below the visible page area).
How can i move my active panel of accordion to the top of the page.It is working fine if i click on panel but not on paqge load with url something like this

```
http://22april/imagine2013.php?id=1$panel=10#accordion
```

This url gives me the active accordion panel but page doesnt comes to top as it comes on clicking the panel.

```
function getParam(name) {
var query = location.search.substring(1);
var myString = query.substr(query.indexOf("$") + 1)

if (myString.length) {
    var parts = myString.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var pos = parts[i].indexOf('=');
        if (parts[i].substring(0,pos) == name) {
        return parts[i].substring(pos+1);
        }
    else{
        return parts[i].substring(pos); 
        }
    }
}
return 0;
} 

$(function () {
   var defaultPanel = parseInt(getParam('panel'));


$("#accordion").accordion({
     heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible:true,
    active:defaultPanel,
    navigation:true,
    activate: function (event, ui) {    //this particular code works when i click on accordion but not when page load and targeted accordion opens on that page.
        var scrollTop = $(".accordion").scrollTop();
        console.log(ui.newHeader);
        if(!ui.newHeader.length) return;

        var top = $(ui.newHeader).offset().top;
        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTop + top - 5
        }, "slow");
    }

});
```

Here is the html part

```
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">

<li><a href="#">TEXT</a>
<ul id="ac1" class="accordion1">
    <li> <a href="#">Title of second accordion</a>
    <ul>Content of second accordion</ul> 
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Please let me know if more information required.
Help me in this.